# Python selenium can't find element in modal

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog

I want to click the button in the modal that opens when I press the button, but it gives an error

my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buy-now-button"]').click()
sleep(5)
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']")
if len(x) > 0:
    y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']")
    y.click()
```

error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']"}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it in an iframe?   or do you need a webdriverwait to ensure your button is available on the page before you attempt to access it?

Comment: @RichEdwards When I press the button, such a waiting screen appears: **[gif](https://i.imgur.com/1LxzvJb.gif)**

Comment: You can see the page is spinning - things are loading without the page changing. That means it's in-page scripts getting new data. You'll need an explicit or implicit wait  before you can access the elements.

Comment: @RichEdwards I'm already using sleep(5) to wait for it to load but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: 've had a look for you - there is an iframe in the modal. see the answer below on how to identify and how to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is within an iframe. If you keep scrolling up in your DOM you'll see this:

[image]

In order to handle iframes with selenium:

1. You need to switch to it
2. You then can complete your action
3. You then need to switch back to the parent frame to continue with the script:

Like this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # this will wait up to 10 seconds for an object to be present

#your code:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buy-now-button"]').click()

#iframe switch:
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'turbo-checkout-iframe')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#your code:
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']")
if len(x) > 0:
    y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']")
    y.click()

#back to the main frame to continue the script 
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

You probably don't need the `find_elements`, and the `if len` parts - you can probably go straight to the click. However the above is an answer to why you cannot find your element.